How to access configs in Laravel during DI container bootstrap initialisation?
I am using Laravel "laravel/framework": "10.22.0",
I want to use php artisan cache:config in order to improve the performance.
I do face one issue when running the command as I am using config('configName' inside bootstrap/container.php and all the results of config function are null.
This is my bootstrap/app.php
<?php

/**
 * @var \Illuminate\Foundation\Application $app
 */

$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

require(__DIR__ . '/container/container.php');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Return The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This script returns the application instance. The instance is given to
| the calling script so we can separate the building of the instances
| from the actual running of the application and sending responses.
|
*/

return $app;


This is a sample of my bootstrap/container/container.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;

/**
 * @var $app Application
 */

//------------------------------------//
//             SERVICES               //
//------------------------------------//

$app->singleton(
    \App\Services\Logger\LoggerContract::class,
    function ($app) {
        $d = config('logger');
        $config = config('mail');
        // the configs above are always null during php artisan config:cache command and this is causing exception and the cache command to fail

        return new \App\Services\Logger\Logger(
            $app,
            config('logger'),
        );
    }
);


I was previously using .env function inside the container and that worked fine.
I moved all envs inside config files as recommended by Laravel documentation in order to have config:cache working but now am facing the issue that config:cache itself fails! as I cannot use config inside container..
If it is not possible to use config during the DI initialisation than it will be ugly to access the configs inside the constructors of the classes instead of receiving them as parameters. It makes testing ugly and harder. With my approach it is normal testing pattern you just change the config array argument during tests.

I solved it in a very weird way.
I was using app->environment() inside config/logger.php and this was causing the issue..
I changed the code to env('APP_ENV') instead then tried php artisan config:cache again and it worked.
There was no issue using config function inside the bootstrap file

Moving into config is a good approach, but I don't think it means it should move to Bootstrap
This is mainly because you're trying to access the variable before it initializes (available).

My suggestion is,
Create a Custom Config File ( config/ directory. (ex filename: abc.php))
<?php

return [
    'api_key' => env('CUSTOM_API_KEY', 'default_key'),
    'api_key2' => env('CUSTOM_API_KEY_2', 'default_value'),
];

In .env (or you can skip this and directly add it to config too)
CUSTOM_API_KEY=your_api_key_here
CUSTOM_API_KEY_2=some_value

You can use
$apiKey = config('abc.api_key');
$apiKey2 = config('abc.api_key2');


php artisan make:provider LoggerServiceProvider

In LoggerServiceProvider.php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Services\Logger\LoggerContract;
use App\Services\Logger\Logger;

class LoggerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(LoggerContract::class, function ($app) {
            $loggerConfig = config('logger'); // add this
            return new Logger($loggerConfig);
        });
    }
}

In config/app.php
'providers' => [
    //...

    App\Providers\LoggerServiceProvider::class,
],


hm.. you are not answering my question. I am doing this already but then I cannot use the config inside container.php, they are always null during the "bootstraping" phase

I need to know how can I define my dependencies then which need the values of the configs ?

For that, create CustomServiceProvider and add it to providers

I am getting other errors now cannot create Exceptions\Handler which is using the logger

@KristiJorgji did you  add to 'providers'?

Run artisan optimize & composer dump if necessary

Yes I added it into the providers array in the kernel file

@KristiJorgji  should be hereconfig/app.php

yes correct added it there

Did you clear the cache or run optimization? Thats the only thing have to do. Nothing else. Its just normal process. Not sure why it not working for you

I removed all the container stuff and still get error  Target class [env] does not exist.  
